# Nodejs getting keys from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am reading a json file in nodejs and want to find a specific key in the json object before doing things with it:

```
fs.readFile('./output.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(Object.keys(data));

});
```

Problem is, it returns an array of numbers as strings:

```
[ '0',
  '1',
  '2',
  '3',
  '4'
  ... ]
```

When my json file has text like this. Why is this happening?

```
[{
    "id": "vdhbsasqzqnbx2od",
    "message": "On Sun, Jan 1, 2012 at 8:17 AM, Alan Stern <ste...@rowland.harvard.edu> wrote:As Linus pointed out, the real problem here 
}, { ...
}]
```

Comment: looks like your ./output.json contains an array so if you want to do something with each object in that array you could do data.forEach(x => console.log(x)) etc

Answer (score 2):

Before I answer why you are getting ['0', '1', etc] as a result, let's see what does your `data` look like. `fs.readFile()` won't give you an object. It also won't give you a string. The `data` is the nodejs [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

Now, when you have a buffer, and you run a `Object.keys()` on it, it returns you the indecies (which are, clearly, `0, 1, 2, etc`).

So to solve your problem, you need to read the data, transform your Buffer into a valid JSON. Once done with that, your object will basically be an array of objects. Now you can perform any action on your array of objects. If you want, for example, to get all messages, you can use `Array.prototype.map`. Check out the example below:

```
fs.readFile('./output.json', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    // This is very important! Whenever you parse a JSON, you have to use try/catch
    try {
        let myArray = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(myArray.map(item => item.message);
    } catch (exc) {
        console.log('Invalid json:', exc);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to run JSON.parse() on the data. Then you can loop through it and access the various properties such as id and message:

```
fs.readFile('./output.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var json = JSON.parse(data);

    json.forEach(function(arrayItem) {
        console.log(arrayItem.message);
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh my.. again.. Never, please, NEVER do a JSON.parse without wrapping it into a try/catch block

Answer (score 0):

Variable `data` is a buffer, so when you pass it to `Object.keys` it returns the keys of the characters of the string (0, 1, 2, 3, ...).

You want to parse the data using `JSON.parse` first and then pass the resulting object to `Object.keys`:

```
fs.readFile('./output.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(Object.keys(JSON.parse(data)));

});
```

**Edit:** Changed 'string' to 'buffer', which was pointed out in the comments.

Comment: It's not a String, it's a Buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You have loop through the array`[]` first then the objects`{}`.

```js
var obj = [{"id":"abc","message":"this is a message"},{"id":"def","message":"another message"}];

for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
    for(key in obj[i]){
      if(obj[i][key] == "abc"){
          return console.log(key);
          }
      }
}
```